# Why did Rabin use $x(x + b)$ instead of just $x^2$ in the original paper?

Tags: history, rabin-cryptosystem

Encryption in the [original Rabin scheme](http://publications.csail.mit.edu/lcs/pubs/pdf/MIT-LCS-TR-212.pdf) took a message $x$ and computed $x(x + b) \bmod n$, where $0 \le b \lt n$ and $n$ is the product of two secret primes $p$ and $q$. The private key is defined as $(p,q)$ and the public key as $(b,n)$. Modern Rabin encryption however is defined as $x^2 \bmod n$, which is equivalent to the original scheme with $b = 0$. Why is $b$ now ignored?

<sub>This question is based on another question which I found interesting but which was mysteriously self-deleted.</sub>

Comment: Note: The original scheme was a _signature_ scheme, not an encryption scheme.

Comment: Specifically, in the original scheme as described by Rabin in 1979, a public key is a pair of integers $(n, b)$ with $0 \leq b < n$, and a signature on a message $M$ is a pair $(x, U)$ of an integer $0 \leq x < n$ and a bit string $U$ such that $x(x + b) \equiv H(M, U) \pmod n$, where $H$ is a randomized hash function.  The signer knows the secret factors $p$ and $q$ of $n$ by which they can solve for $x$ modulo $p$ and $q$ separately (if it exists, otherwise retry with another $U$).  The paper uses the slightly confusing notation $C(MU)$, for ‘compressing function’, where I wrote $H(M, U)$.

Comment: The [description on Wikipedia today](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Rabin_signature_algorithm&oldid=850818393) is bad and misrepresents nearly all of the details from the original paper; obviously it was written by someone—or by a stumbling uncoordinated collective—who never bothered to actually read the paper and instead transcribed a secondhand game of telephone, as is mandated by the priests of Wikipedia who are apparently allergic to primary sources.

Comment: The factoring reduction, Theorems 1 and 2, applies to any square root algorithm, which can be derived, as the paper shows, from an $x(x+b)$ forger: to compute $\sqrt m$, find $x$ solving $x(x+b)=m-(b/2)^2$, since then $m=x^2+bx+(b/2)^2=(x+b/2)^2$ so that $x+b/2=\pm\sqrt m$. The algorithms for using the private key to solve $x(x+b)=c$ detailed in §2 are simpler if $b=0$: for $p\equiv3\pmod4$, compute $\pm(c+b^2/4)^{(p + 1)/4}-b/2$; for $p\equiv1\pmod4$, compute $$\gcd(x^{(p-1)/2}-1,(x+\delta)^2+b(x+\delta)-c)$$ for random $\delta$ until a factor $x+\delta-\alpha$ falls out and return $\alpha$.

Comment: [Galbraith's book](https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~sgal018/crypto-book/crypto-book.html) has a [footnote on p. 513](https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~sgal018/crypto-book/ch24.pdf#page=7) commenting that although the original scheme used $x(x + b)$, setting $b = 0$ improves efficiency with no loss in security, which seems obvious from Rabin's paper.  The first edition of Stinson's book uses $x(x + b)$ without saying why; later editions just use $x^2$.  Menezes, van Oorschot, and Vanstone (HAC) mention that the original paper used $x(x + b)$, but only describe $x^2$ for encryption and signature.

Comment: You could try emailing Michael Rabin!